# Square roots of non-negative commuting operators commute

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

While reading some papers on Quantum Information theory, I observed that several theorems required working with square roots of non-negative operators. So I thought of proving some operator results so as to get comfortable. So far I've been successful, but I am having some trouble proving the following assertion.

If $A$ and $B$ are non-negative bounded operators on a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$, then $A$ and $B$ commute iff $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{B}$ commute.

I was able to show $\sqrt{A}$,$\sqrt{B}$ commute $\Rightarrow$ $A$,$B$ commute via
$$AB = \sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}=\cdots=\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}$$

As for the reverse implication, I did the following
$$AB=BA \iff \sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}$$

This expansion didn't get me anywhere. So I thought of proving $\sqrt{AB}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$. By uniqueness of square root, $\sqrt{AB}=\sqrt{BA}=\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}$ and I would be done. I'm not sure how to prove this though. Squaring rhs gives $(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B})^2=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$. But that looks just as convoluted.

I'd appreciate any hints on how to proceed.

Comment: You aren't using the fact that the square roots are also positive, which is what makes them unique. Once you do everything you want follows from the continuous functional calculus.

Comment: I was actually looking for a proof that didn't require heavy machinery. It appears that I am not so lucky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, then $B$ commutes with $p(A)$ for all polynomials $p$.  Since $A^\frac{1}{2}$ is a limit of polynomials of $A$, it follows that $B$ commutes with $A^\frac{1}{2}$.  By the same reasoning, it follows that $A^\frac{1}{2}$ commutes with $B^\frac{1}{2}$.